# How to create already made collections when i register a user account on firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm using flutter with firebase, when i register an account into firebase how do i get a `.collection('userData').document(uid)`

`.collection('bio')` already make with that account, what i want to do is, when i create the account, some data is already in the 'bio' documents for me in the cloud Firestore  such as:

```
name: ""

age: ""

date: ""

height:  ""
```

and so on, then all i have to do is fill out those fields to  show on my  app, i'm doing this for all the students in my school, and i can do it manually but that will take way to long since its way over 5,000 students, or is it even possible to copy the .collection with one array of data  such as the one above and paste in into each user 'bio' document and go from there with each of them instead of having to keep adding fields for each one.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear and Firebase products are NoSQL and don't have pre-defined fields like SQL does. When you write the field data, the field is created with it. In fact if you write field data into a document that's part of a collection that doesn't exist - ALL of that data is created automatically - the collection, the document, the fields and the data.

Comment: So, if I wanted to add information to an account I created via firebase for over 5,000 people i'll have to do it manually? for each student?

Comment: Note sure I understand the question. As the user enters their data into your app, it would be added to Firestore or the RTDB. Likewise if you have an existing roster of students you could either write an app that uploads it, which should be pretty straightforward or if you're using the RTDB, you could upload the file as JSON. Bottom line is that the data needs to get into Firebase one way or the other but the question is unclear about your process or what you're trying to do exactly.